# Slow response on $http post request

Tags: http, ionic-framework

I created a mobile application and it loads data from a php server by $http post.

Everything works fine and I get response correctly but so slow.
Details of the request and response time (safari network log):

[image]

P.S:
It's not the internet, I've tested it with high-speed DSL (50mb/s), and the server is Amazon EC2 so I don't think the hardware is the problem.

If you check the request has 10sec latency - I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: have you tried alone with backend using some tool like Postman to see the response ? may be backend is not that responsive ?

Comment: @Roxy I believe everything is okay with the backend because it is also connected to a website and works perfectly good there (that one is angular too) but when it comes to ionic everything's slow.